# ADB connection not working because of a double port

Tags: android, port, virtual-machine, adb, vmware

i'm trying to connect from VMware guest to an Android Emulator that runs on the host.
This emulator is connected to port 5554.
I tried Both with NAT and Bridged network.
and this is what i get anytime:

```
root@dev-virtual-machine:~# adb connect 10.100.102.8:5554
unable to connect to 10.100.102.8:5554:5554
```

Tried forward the port and changing the tcpip:

```
root@dev-virtual-machine:~# adb forward tcp:5555 tcp:5554
root@dev-virtual-machine:~# adb tcpip 5554
restarting in TCP mode port: 5554
root@dev-virtual-machine:~# adb connect 10.100.102.8
unable to connect to 10.100.102.8:5555
```

But i still get the same error with the double port problem.

From the host when i run this:

```
adb connect localhost:5554
```

It does work.

Comment: You should only be adding the 10.100.102.8 in your adb connect call because you have already defined the port. `adb connect 10.100.102.8`.

Comment: this is what i see:
   root@dev-virtual-machine:~# `adb connect 10.100.102.8`
   `unable to connect to 10.100.102.8:5555`

Comment: What type of connection does your VMware guest use? NAT or Bridged? Can you connect from the host at all?

Comment: Then the first command should have been `adb tcpip 5554` before your `adb connect 10.100.102.8`.  That should define the connection for the appropriate port.

Comment: i don't get why everywhere anyone saying to run `adb tcpip` what this command does is it's changing the connected device listenning port to whatever port you choose (but i did tried that either)

Comment: Sorry if you are not working over tcpip wireless connection you can ignore, but i thought that is what you wanted was to change the port to 5554.  Perhaps just connect.

Comment: I do want to change the port to 5554. but the adb CLI port. not my a device port...

Comment: Can you ping your host?

Comment: Yes I can ping my host

Comment: From the host I tried `adb connect localhost:5554` and it worked. I disconnected and I tried `adb connect ip_pingable_from_guest:5554` and it didn't work :)

Comment: maybe the Emulator has some kind of firewall that accept only data from localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after i tried a lot of options i figured out that the problem was that Android Emulator listens only on traffic that comes from 127.0.0.1(localhost) so there are a couple of solutions:
1. I think there is an option in the emulator config that allows outside traffic. 
2. SSH Forwarding.
3. Set up some kind of a proxy from outside the Host to inside

Comment: Yes - it's not really a firewall though, it's merely that it only listens on loopback (whenever you listen a socket, you can specify one interface, or any).  There does, however, appear to be a command line option in recent versions which changes that behavior.

Comment: Thanks! i fixed that. what option is it?